# Create a consistent view of an AWS Postgres RDS schema?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS postgres read replica consuming from another RDS instance.  I'd like to get a consistent view on all the tables in a particular schema such that I can query them for ETL purposes.

What I'm trying to do is similar to pg_dump, but I'd rather just get the consistent view of the schema and query the tables, rather than writing them out to a separate file.

Right now we're using snapshots of the production database, restoring them and streaming from there, but saving the snapshot takes a long time due to load and read performance from the snapshotted database is quite poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using exactly the same thing that pg_dump does: use a "repeatable read" transaction:

BEGIN;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

execute queries

COMMIT;